# Let $a>0$ and let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Assume the sequence $y_{n}=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n^a}$ is bounded.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $a>0$ and let $x_n$ be a sequence of real numbers. Assume the sequence $y_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n}{n^a}$ is bounded. show that for each $b>a$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n^b}$ is convergent.

My attempt: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x_n}{n^b} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x_n}{n^{b-a+a}} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^{b-a}} \frac{x_n}{n^a}$.

Let $a_n=\frac{x_n}{n^a}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^{b-a}}$. Clearly, $b_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing and approaches to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$.
Can we say the partial sum of $a_{n}$ is bounded?

Comment: When I try to take the partial sum this is $\frac{x_{1}}{1^{a}}+\frac{x_{2}}{2^{a}}+........+\frac{x_{n}}{n^{a}}$, How I say this is $y_{n}$.

Comment: Have you tried using the summation by parts formula?

Comment: No. I just  try with summation by parts.